# Prevent Input from Being Printed in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know if it is possible to prevent an input from being printed in Python 3.

```
x = int(input())

def func(n):
    if n%2==0:
        print("Even")
    else:
        print("Odd")

func(x)
```

In the code above, for instance, if I input "236", the console prints:

```
236
Even
```

I would like the output to be just:

```
Even
```

Thanks!

I've heard this was possible in Python 2.x with the raw_input() function.

Comment: FYI: the [release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) for Python 3.0 say "`raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`. That is, the new `input()` function reads a line from `sys.stdin` and returns it with the trailing newline stripped...", which is to say that Python 3.x `input()` *is* `raw_input()`

Answer (score 4):

If you type an input, it's being displayed on screen by your terminal before Python even sees it.

To suppress this, use [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html), which is normally used for password input:

```
from getpass import getpass

x = int(getpass(prompt=''))
```

Note that you still see the newline being printed, resulting in an empty line.